# ReCaptcha not loading Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, recaptcha, contacts

I'm using Contact form 7 and my ReCaptcha isn't showing. The keys are correct and the shortcode is correct.

This is the code that is showing on Google Inspect but it's completely blank:

```
<div class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"><div data-sitekey="6LfyPQ4UAAAAAPyk1crFfHTiKVQ7wpBwPPWyBqCK" data-theme="dark" data-size="compact" class="wpcf7-form-control g-recaptcha wpcf7-recaptcha"></div>
<noscript>
</noscript>
</div>
```

Link to live site (wait for CF7 popup):
http://globalenergycertification.org/

Comment: You apparently got this to work - how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate other plugins then test ReCaptcha. And active again the plugins. Let me know what happen.